Why return the Month object from this operator overloader function?
I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's "Principle and Practice using C++". In chapter 9.6 about operator overloading, he gives the following example of defining the incrementing operator ++ for the enum class Month:
enum class Month {
    Jan=1, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
};
    
Month operator++(Month& m)                                 // prefix increment operator
{
    m = (m==Month::Dec) ? Month::Jan : Month(static_cast<int>(m)+1);       
    return m;
}

He then says it could be used like this:
Month m = Month::Sep;
++m;       // m becomes Oct
++m;       // m becomes Nov
++m;       // m becomes Dec
++m;       // m becomes Jan (“wrap around”)

But, I don't understand the point of returning a Month when you pass the Month object by reference and change it. Why not write the function like this?
void operator++(Month& m)                                 // prefix increment operator
{
    m = (m==Month::Dec) ? Month::Jan : Month(static_cast<int>(m)+1);       
}

The code ran fine when I tested. I am wondering what I have overlooked since this Stroustrup guy knows the language quite well :)

Because defining this as a void function would make it work counter to how ++ works for other types?

A prefix increment operator should be returning a reference.

Typically chaining so you can do stuff like result = A + B + C; or func(A + B). But in the case of ++ you either return the original value (x++) or the resulting value (++x) so that the caller can take further actions. func(++x) and func(x++) can do very different things because they (usually) get different values.

Does this answer your question? What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?

When you override operators, you're supposed to override them in the expected fashion.
You probably tested something like:
Month month = Month::SEP;
++month;

But, what happens if you try to do something like this?
Month October = ++month;

This should be a legal operation, but your operator++() method returns void, so it won't work properly.
The return from the operator++() method needs to return a reference to the object, because people will use ++foo in an expression, including expressions that may modify the object.
Hence, your function signature should be:
Month& operator++(Month& m)
{
    return m = (m==Month::Dec) ? Month::Jan : Month(static_cast<int>(m)+1);       
}


@user3612 You have to pass in the object as a reference parameter because the operator needs to know which object to modify. The operator is being defined as a standalone function, it can't be defined as a method of the enum, so this is not available in this case. And returning the object is to allow the caller to save the modified value to another variable, or to chain a subsequent expression.
